# Button background color is changed by portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android

I am new to Android Application development. In my application if I click on button,it changes it background color from black to green.
If I change the mode from portrait to landscape then it changes the color from green to black with out click on button.

My requirement is,have to stop  background color change,by changing the mode from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait.

Please help me to go forward.

Answer (score 1):

When screen orientation changes, the method `onCreate()` is called.

My guess is you are calling `Button.setBackgroundColor()` in this `onCreate()` method...

Try surrounding this call with `if(savedInstanceBundle == null){}`, like that it will only set the color to black on the first `onCreate()` call, and not for any subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate device then `onCreate()` method calls again to avoid this use below code

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in the Manifest.xml for activity

```
<activity
     android:name="com.sample.stackoverflow.MainActivity"
     android:configChanges="orientation"
     android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

If you want to load specific layout when orientation change :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // use your setcontentView here
}
```

Comment: 1.On button click only i set background for button.2.I already use the below code android:configChanges="orientation" in my manifest.xml file.3.I use different layout for landscape mode in layout-land folder.

Comment: So you need to set boolean value in variable . so that you from this value you set background color. cause you are using different layout. so thats why changes not reflect

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity declaration in manifest. Like this

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```